# How to optimize assignation process in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I want place 1 million fish in a lake at random to do so i have this.
`ask patches[ if sum [peces] of patches < 1000000 [ask one-of patches with [mallor = 1][set peces peces + 1]]]`

This is taking too long, how would you suggest to make it quicker? I know it´s the sum part as it has to always check, but i dont know how else to do it

Answer (score 0):

A first thing I noticed is that you have the construction:

`ask patches [ if ... [ ask one-of patches [...]]]`

That first `ask patches` is completely redundant here. It lets each patch direct another random patch to make a fish. Since you use `one-of` the second time around I don't expect that the speed impact is too big but it should still help

Next, I suggest counting the fish you have already placed with a single local variable, instead of using `sum [peces] of patches` 1000000 times. Getting variables from an agent (with `of` or `with`) takes a lot of time if you have a lot of agents, and I remember from your previous questions that your number of patches is pretty huge.

Then thirdly, you also check for which patches the `mallor = 1` condition is true 1000000 times. That one can also be grouped into a local agentset

```
let fish-placed 0
let mallor_patches patches with [mallor = 1 ]

while [fish-placed < 1000000] [
    ask one-of mallor_patches [
        set peces peces + 1
        set fish-placed fish-placed + 1
    ]
]
```

Disclaimer, I haven't tested any of this code in Netlogo since I don't have the  bigger model to test the code in. However I expect it will run a many times faster than what you originally wrote.

Comment: If you could, please let me know how big the effect of the three suggestions separately was. I'm quite interested in the result myself

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. I solved it by making 1000 fish agents and giving them the "school" variables and gave it another number. However, i can do yours too, to check. :) Thanks again